# Unable to show popover for a button in xib file

Tags: iphone, swift

I have a xib file in which there are multiple buttons. I am able to provide functionality to those buttons except one. For one button, I need to show a popover. I've researched and got results for classes inheriting UIViewController but not for UIView.

In detail, I have 3 files - CustomView.xib (in which there are multiple buttons), CustomView.swift (Class to deal with CustomView.xib) and PopView.xib (which I should load one clicking a button in CustomView.xib)

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: In iOS a popover generally uses it's own view controller, which *has* a view. What's your *specific* issue? Can you show us what you've actually tried?

Answer (score 0):

The presentingViewController should be responsible for the popover not the UIView. You can write a method in your custom UIView class to present the popover via the presentingViewController